# How to calculate largest integer that cannot be represented by a linear combination 6a+7b?

Tags: integers

How to calculate largest integer that cannot be represented by a linear combination $6a+7b=x$ if $x$ is the integer?

Comment: cf. the [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: I assume you mean for $a$ and $b$ must both be non-negative.  Otherwise, note that $1=6\cdot (-1)+7\cdot (1)$ and so *every* integer $x$ can be represented as some $6a+7b$, namely $6\cdot (-x)+7\cdot (x)$